# How do I position Table View Content so it doesn't bump the top

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am working in Xcode 5 using storyboard and Table View Controller to build an indexed view. The view also has a search box. The interface references a .plist file for content.

Everything is working correctly. The data loads, the search works correctly, but the content is jammed up against the top of the view and overlaps the carrier signal and battery indicator.

[image]

I have tried modifying the positioning of the search box as follows:

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]
                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 44)];
```

However, changing these numbers does not impact the positioning. If I apply the same efforts in a Navigation controller it displays correctly:

[image]

How do I resolve this layout issue in the first Table View instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing new property called edgesForExtendedLayout in iOS7.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

**edgesForExtendedLayout**
Use edgesForExtendedLayout to specify which edges of a view should be extended, regardless of bar translucency. This will adjust the edges for the extended layout in iOS 7. By default, the value of this property is UIRectEdgeAll.

**automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets**
If you don’t want a scroll view’s content insets to be automatically adjusted, set automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to NO. When set to YES the scroll view will reside under the status bar and navigation bar but the content will adjust below. When you scroll the content, it will move under the navigation and status bar.

**extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars**
This value is just an addition to the previous ones. If the status bar is opaque, the views won't be extended to include the status bar too, unless this parameter is YES.